# Ionic 2 - Property Binding to make app invisible

Tags: properties, binding, ionic2, opacity, invisible

I'm a bit of a noob to ionic so this may be a dumb question.

On the press of a button I want to overlay my entire app with a black image (or make everything invisible) but still have the buttons working underneath.

My app is based on the tab sample app.

So far I've tried the following

app.scss

```
.dark-overlay {
background-color: #000 !important;
opacity: 1;
}
```

my-tab.html

```
<ion-content class="dark-overlay" (ng-hide)="showOverlay">
....
<div tappable (click)="stealthMode()"><img src="assets/img/stealthMode.png" width="100%" scroll="false"></div>
```

my-tab.ts

```
stealthMode () {
this.myElements = document.querySelectorAll("dark-overlay");
for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
myElements[i].style.opacity = 0;
}
}
```

Even if i can get this to work it's not going to be the final answer as setting the opacity in app.scss to 0 still leaves the tabbar visible but I need that to go black too.

I think it's related to property binding.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about efficiency of 'stealthMode' function. You already show/hide the '.dark-overlay' div using ng-hide.

Comment: Thanks can you give me a little example of how that would look in code?

Answer (score 2):

you need to use pointer-events to let events go through your dark overlay. 
I have demonstrated that in this [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/zJFaYit6hX3C7m6L7Nfc?p=preview) (go to second tab which shows home page)

style.css

```
.dark-overlay{
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background-color:#888;
 opacity:0.9;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 z-index:1000;
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

and have this in home.html

```
<button (click)="stealthMode()">Tint</button>  
<div class="dark-overlay" [hidden]="showOverlay"></div>
```

and this in home.ts

```
showOverlay:boolean = false;
  stealthMode(){
    this.showOverlay = !this.showOverlay;
  }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the pointer (pardon the pun).  I'm still not sure how I use that in the .html and .ts files.  Does it appear correct to you?  Also if I have the issue with not being able to hide the tab bar.  Sorry I haven't been able to test your response as I'm not at the code at the moment.  Thanks again.

Comment: That's brilliant thanks.  I can't wait to get home and test it out.  The only bit I need to solve is to make the tab bar itself invisible.  I think if I apply the dark-overlay class to the tabs themselves.  It will become a little more complex as each individual tab will have the stealthMode button and I'll need to apply the invisibility globally using my shared-data service.  But you've got me on the right track.  Thanks.

Comment: I decided to just hide the tabbar when everything is hidden.  I used this provider and added it to my view.  https://gist.github.com/0x1ad2/e32859546b1bfeff5c55ceddf221e5b2 All works great now thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make a binding to render that part dynamically using angular directives.

Check this for clean implementation:  
[ngIF](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html)